# Decrease in no. of page views on GIS SE

Tags: discussion, statistics

Page views on GIS SE have been significantly reduced from ca. mid of May this year: what is the reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although framed as a New Visits rather than Page Views question, the reason for this has been discussed on Meta Stack Exchange as [Why has there been such a huge drop in "new visits" since May 9th, 2022, across multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047/215590)

Answer (score 2):

There is a cycle on message boards and forums and social media sites. When one is set up, it is a lot of fun to post there. Then various trolls take it too far and there is a call for stricter moderation. Then the moderators start to become more strict. Eventually it is not any fun to post on the site, so even the regular users stop posting there. They move on to a newer site that has less moderation. Then the rules and moderation proliferates at the new site, and the cycle continues.

I get it, moderation is hard and thankless. It is also necessary. But at the rules grow more numerous engagement often goes down. It's a pattern. Though it might not explain the precipitous drop in that chart, it is a real effect.